# MediaStore: Deletes all ident Songs from Playlist

Tags: java, android, android-contentresolver, playlist, mediastore

When I have 2 Songs with the same audioID in a Playlist and I want to delete **only 1 of those** 2 songs, what should I change to this code?

```
static public int removeSongFromPlaylist(Context ctx, long playlist_id, long song_id) {
        ContentResolver resolver = ctx.getContentResolver();
        Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.getContentUri("external", playlist_id);

        int res = resolver.delete(uri, MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.AUDIO_ID+" = "+song_id, null);
        reloadPlaylistList(ctx);
        return res;
    }
```

Because this deletes ALL Songs with the audioID given from the parameters.

*I thought about checking how many songs were deleted and if they are more than 1 i just add them again. But this would mess up the order of the playlist and I think it isn't very effective.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`delete(Uri url, String where, String[] selectionArgs)`

```
Uri uri = ...
String where = "song_id=? LIMIT 1";
String[] args = new String{song_id};
```

now `resolver(uri, where, args);`

Comment: The above works fine if you have only 2 duplicates. What if you have 3 or more?. I have resolved this problem by using the lastIndexOf() function. I build up an array of all audio_ids, Start looping around them and test for lastIndexOf(audio_id). If the result is larger then we have a duplicate. Remove the audio_id at this position and test again. Now If lastIndexOf(audio_id) == position we have no further duplicates so we move on.